# Spyder console keeps rebooting when operating a RegEx code block

Tags: python, regex, anaconda, spyder

I am preparing a code to identify the columns in a dataframe with the word "date" in their names. I am using RegEx for comparing the sub-strings generated from the original names using re.split() function.
This is the entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\rishi\Desktop\PGDBDA\Dataset\Dataset for Date Operations.xlsx')
#print(df)
# Dataset is loaded into Pandas dataframe

column_name = [names for names in df.columns]
#print(column_name)
# The column names are extracted into a list called column_name.
# We plan use a mechanism to identify the sub-string 'date' from the elements in column_name.

name_split = []
for index in column_name:
name_split.append(re.split(' |-|_',index))
#print(name_split)
# Using RegEx we are able to split the elements in the column name based on a set of dilimiters.
# We are grouping them in a list of lists nammed as name_split.  

column_index = []
column_count = 0
regex_pattern = re.compile(r"\bdate\b", re.IGNORECASE)

for index in name_split:
    for elements in index:
       if re.search(regex_pattern, elements) != None:
                    column_index.append(column_count)
                    exit()        
    column_count+=1        
print(column_index)
# Will tell us all the columns with 'date' in their names, by stating the index no of the column.
```

The issue is that every time I am running this portion of the code:

```
column_index = []
column_count = 0
regex_pattern = re.compile(r"\bdate\b", re.IGNORECASE)

for index in name_split:
    for elements in index:
        if re.search(regex_pattern, elements) != None:
                   column_index.append(column_count)
                exit()        
column_count+=1        
print(column_index)
# Will tell us all the columns with 'date' in their names, by stating the index no of the column.
```

The console keeps crashing and reloading. Any insight on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try code in normal console/termina/cmd.exe to see if it will display any error.

Comment: did you try without `exit()` ? Maybe it may exit console too. mabye you should use `break` to exit only `for`-loop, not all code. OR put code in function and use `return` to exit only function.

Comment: @furas, thanks a lot. You were correct. I replaced exit() with break and it worked.